# Performance of ffmpeg decoding on android without neon support

Tags: android, ffmpeg, arm, frame-rate, neon

I've compiled ffmpeg code on android and able to play the video without neon support and for armv5te. Decoding is good, the video plays,but the problem is the frame rate is really really bad. I getting a max of 5fps, which is horrible.

Is there anybody who has got success in playing the video without support with ffmpeg on android. Or is there anything that I am really missing?

EDIT : configuration I got it by running

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libgsm --enable-libxvid \
--enable-libamr_nb --enable-libamr_wb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libogg \
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-shared
```

Comment: also, device information might be handy. Unless you are trying to make this work on all Android devices

Comment: At present I'm working on droid x and is targetted only for droid x

Comment: I have compiled the FFMPEG library but while creating wrapper for it using jni_wrapper.c file it's giving undefined reference error. Is there any changes i have to make in Android.mk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get anything working without neon support. So I compiled with neon support and for armv7. I get better framerate now. Nearly 40fps, is very good enough for my app needs. Thanks matthew for your responses.

Comment: Hey Android007, could you share your arm7library with neon support? how was the processing time and for how many seconds of video? Im actually targeting more recent android devices with better processsors as well as iOS devices.

Comment: what resolution is that 40fps?

Answer (score 2):

I've done substantial video decoding on the Galaxy Tab using ffmpeg with performance to spare to meet the 60fps [glbuffer](http://github.com/richq/glbuffer) expects. I think that in theory I could use neon with the Tab, but I wasn't able to get it working.

Unfortunately, I can't speak for other devices.

**Edit** - my ffmpeg config line is:

```
--enable-static --disable-shared --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver \
--disable-avdevice --disable-neon --disable-network \
--disable-swscale-alpha --enable-zlib --enable-memalign-hack \
--disable-stripping --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm5te \
--enable-armv5te --target-os=linux --cc=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
--extra-cflags='-fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb'
```

I wonder if it's the armv5te that is giving me the boost.

I ran into problems trying to load the shared version from my Java code, and so I used a static version instead. I don't think this would impact performance, though.

**Edit** - I patterned my config line after [this gist](https://gist.github.com/828227/05c9da6648ad4067ee509f14d3bac77f84408a44)

Comment: If possible could you please share your configuration? Or do you think I am missing with something?

Comment: I can post it when I get home. Maybe you could post the device you're using and your configuration as well?

Comment: I have edited the question to add the configuration as attachment

Comment: also, how many threads are you using? Do you have both a renderer and a decoder thread? Are you using GLSurfaceView?

Comment: I have only 2 threads and I am using glbuffer. Forgot to mention, I'm using droid x

Comment: Did it fail to compile? By the way, I'm using the "standalone toolchain".

Comment: Matthew, Thanks for your response. This doesn't help me either, I get an error "arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file." need to look for a different solution.

Comment: I got that as well at first... did you do the inital setup for the standalone sdk?

Comment: What is standalone SDK? I am using the NDK_R5B(not SDK at this point of time)  arm-linux-android-eabi-4.4.3 tool chain which is included in the ndk-r5b. Are you referring to the same?

Comment: The docs for the "standalone toolchain" are in docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html in your ndk folder. There is some setup you need to do before you can start using configure scripts

Comment: I am able to run that script anyway. Let me see whether I'll get a better frame rate with it. Thanks for all the help.